# what kind of equation is this and how can I solve it?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I was wondering if anyone can tell me about this equation:
$$
f(x) = f(y)+cx
$$
How can I select points for this equation and graph it?  What values are constant and what values are changing?  Thanks

Comment: Assuming $x$ and $y$ are variables, you can't graph or solve this as is. Do you have any other constraints?

Comment: Do you mean that you'd like to graph $y$ as a function of $x$?  In that case, it depends on the function $f(x)$.

Comment: Well, maybe the x is a substitution for ln(a/y)... then it would read: f(ln(a/y))=f(y)+c*ln(a/y)

Comment: Assuming $f$ has an inverse, then you could write $y$ as a function of $x$ by noting $y = f^{-1}(f(x)-cx)$

Comment: Yes, actually, f is an inverse!  f^(-1)(x)=f^(-1)(y)+cx  That is actually the equation...